# Why does my numpy install keeps being KILLED?

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv

here's what I am trying to do on Coding Ground

```
sh-4.3$ pip install --target=. virtualenv
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-15.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8MB)
    100% |################################| 1.8MB 204kB/s
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv
sh-4.3$ python virtualenv.py mine
New python executable in /home/cg/root/mine/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
sh-4.3$ . mine/bin/activate
(mine) sh-4.3$ pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.11.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (15.3MB)
    99% |############################### | 15.3MB 43.1MB/s eta 0:00:01Killed
(mine) sh-4.3$
```

Why does my trying of installation of numpy keep being killed?
And how do i solve this problem?

Comment: Running out of memory is one possible reason.

Comment: How do I solve it? please.

Comment: Running out of disk quota is another possible reason.

Comment: This is related to this question which i put a bounty of +100 points on now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634645/how-would-i-install-numpy-library-on-coding-ground

Answer (score 4):

A quick fix for this would be to add swap memory. Here's an Ubuntu example:

```
sudo mkdir /media/fasthdd
dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/fasthdd/swapfile.img bs=1024 count=1M
sudo mkswap /media/fasthdd/swapfile.img
sudo swapon /media/fasthdd/swapfile.img
```

Don't forget to turn it off if you don't need it.